# Ubuntu won't accept password

Tags: 14.04, password, password-recovery, passwd

I have a notebook with Ubuntu 14.04 installed...
My user is set to auto login, but everytime I need to input the password (for installing applications for example), it won't accept the actual password...
I tried to reset it in recovery, but it doesn't work too...

Answer (score 1):

After booting into recovery mode, you must remember to re-mount the root filesystem as read-write, otherwise changing the password will have no effect. Follow the instructions here to reset your password: https://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/10/change-forgotten-password-ubuntu-14-04-servers/

Comment: I did re-mount it, but it still doesn't change the password

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem with installing Ubuntu 16.04 and I solved it by changing the password and removing any parentheses in my password and I have used only characters and numbers and dots to separate between the characters. Now I am longing to my root account with full permission.

Comment: Numbers in your password are encouraged for security, and will not cause any issues.  Numbers are just character codes, just like letters, and get treated the same way.

Comment: The problem was with the parentheses from the password, that's what happen with me.